# need help with inductor RLC circuit

Tags: inductor, passive-networks, iron-core

I found a mediocre source that kind of helps me. I want to find the magnetic permeability of an inductor core based on changes to the rlc circuit.

The source I found is here: https://old.joam.inoe.ro/arhiva/pdf8_5/5Hristoforou1.pdf

The equation that I need is on page 4. [image]

However, the paper fails to prove this equation. Can somebody help me prove this or find a source that has the proof of the equation (I checked the sources and appendix, but no luck). Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is another paper they are referencing for the equation?